# How to receive array within Vardictonary in Native Client send from javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I am sending dictionary with string and array from javascript to native client like

```
   var paramdata=[]  //with values

   common.naclModule.postMessage({'message' : 'Configuration',
                                 'param_array' : paramdata});
```

and trying to receive from native client like

```
    if (var_message.is_dictionary()) {
     pp::VarArray param_array;
       pp::VarDictionary dictionary_js(var_message);
       std::string js_message = dictionary_js.Get("message").AsString();
       if(js_message == "Configuration")
       {
                pp::Var var(dictionary_js.Get("param_array"));
```

but it gives error like **error: no match for call to `(pp::VarArray) (pp::Var&)'**...what is the proper way to get array from dictionary.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got answer..i have to use **pp::VarArray array = dictionary_js.Get("param_array")** instead of **pp::Var var(dictionary_js.Get("param_array"));**

Comment: Please add the answer yourself, and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer.. I have to use

```
pp::VarArray array = dictionary_js.Get("param_array");
```

instead of

```
pp::Var var(dictionary_js.Get("param_array"));
```